# Why is fbox leaving padding on the left and right of my includegraphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm new to Tex, and it's my first time writing a paper on tex, so please bear with me.
When I tried to put a border around a `\includegraphics` inside a `\tikzpicture` using `\fbox`, there is a mysterious gap on the left and right of my picture and the border.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (digit1) at (-4, 2){
        {%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
        \fbox{        
        \includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{samplephoto}
        }
        }%
    };
```

Even after setting the `\fboxsep` to `0pt`, there is still this gap on the left and right. Can anybody help?

Comment: Try `\fbox{%` and as well after `\includegraphics....%`

Answer (score 5):

Compare the two variants: `\fbox{% ....\includegraphics...}%` and without `%` -- the original version introduces white space, enlarging the box!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}



\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%


\fbox{       
  \includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{samplephoto}
}

\fbox{%        
  \includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{samplephoto}%
}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think having a `%` after `\fbox{%` followed by the subsequent macro(s) on the _same_ line might be confusing to some. Better to switch to "display" mode for that.  i.e., The `\fbox{% ....\includegraphics...}%` should be on _two_ lines,  _not_ one in the intro paragraph.  Either that or refer to the two variants as "`\fbox{%` and `\fbox{ ` (without a percent character)".

Answer (score 3):

In tikzpicture use of `\fbox{...}` is nonsense. Just exploit node options (of course with respect of correct TikZ syntax):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,line width=1pt, inner sep=0pt] (digit1) at (-4, 2)
        {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{samplephoto}};%
\end{tikzpicture};
```

[image]

However, this approach has sense only if your image is only a part of TikZ picure. Otherwise is better to use suggestion in Christian Hupfer answer.

Comment: It's true: `\fbox` makes no sense for `tikz` environment. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (digit1) at (-4, 2){\frame{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{samplephoto}}};
```